# android supporting old api with annotations

Tags: android, annotations, compatibility

I have a button which opens contact activity (I want user to choose a contact), button looks like this:

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/ok1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/button_contact"
    android:onClick="contact"
/>
```

contact function just open new activity:

```
public void contact(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI is provided from API level 5 (ECLAIR). So I added @TargetApi(5) above my function:

```
@TargetApi(5)
public void contact(View view) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
   startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

And I hide this button in onCreate method:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR){
    findViewById(R.id.ok1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

But I still have an exception when activity starts:

```
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591): java.lang.VerifyError: com.krinsen.world.ui.MultiplayerActivity
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
07-21 08:36:26.223: E/AndroidRuntime(591):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This exception tells me nothing. Can anyone help?
If I remove contact function, activity starts normaly. But it's not a solution becouse it's not working on new devices (when button is visible).

Comment: Have you resolved this bug ? Ty